# API call to capture the Daily Step Count from google fit api's

Tags: google-api, google-fit

I am trying to get daily Step count to display on my Personal Dashboard which I plan to run as an end of the job.

When I try to access this api end point with access token and required authentication, I am having no luck. It's only allowing me to enter a small dataset range.

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps/datasets/1470475368-1471080168

Any help to retrieve a daily step count if possible with a single call, will be really appreciated.

Comment: The units of the your `datasetId` look wrong: these look like they are seconds; [they should be in nanoseconds](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get).

Comment: @andyTurner : I appreciate your quick response. I figured out where I was doing wrong. I was giving a larger date range and my bad.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the Daily Steps Total](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total) using the Fit Android API and Fit REST API.

> Your app can read the current daily step count total across all data
>   sources by making a `POST` request and querying the
>   `com.google.step_count.delta` data type for the specified time period.
>
> **HTTP method**
>
> `POST`
>
> **Request URL**
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate
> ```
>
> Request body
>
> ```
> {
>   "aggregateBy": [{
>     "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
>     "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
>   }],
>   "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
>   "startTimeMillis": 1438705622000,
>   "endTimeMillis": 1439310422000
> }
> ```
>
> **Curl command**
>
> ```
> curl \
> -X POST \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json;encoding=utf-8" \
> -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
> -d @aggregate.json \
> https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I tried both the Curl and HTTP route. 

For Curl, even though I got the right Access Token from the OAuth Playground, it's throwing an Credential Error.

For HTTP route, the start time and the end time gap has to be very small within minutes for it to work. 

I was looking if there is anything that can help me get the data for previous day.

Comment: @vullankib Does it work if you issue the request in [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22aggregateBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22dataTypeName%22%3A%22com.google.step_count.delta%22%2C%22dataSourceId%22%3A%22derived%3Acom.google.step_count.delta%3Acom.google.android.gms%3Aestimated_steps%22%7D%5D%2C%22bucketByTime%22%3A%7B%22durationMillis%22%3A86400000%7D%2C%22startTimeMillis%22%3A1438705622000%2C%22endTimeMillis%22%3A1439310422000%7D%7D)?

Comment: @AndyTurner: I did try the try it now option as well, but no luck. It has the same constraint as the HTTP request, the start time and end time gap should be kept very minimal. 
"aggregate duration too large" - Error is appearing.

Comment: @vullankib the link in my comment sets the values you have provided, and I don't get the error. You would only get that error message if you request aggregation of more than 90 days. If this is the error message you are getting, it does help if you say that in your question.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I appreciate your quick response. I figured out where I was doing wrong. I was giving a larger date range and my bad.